# How to put all file names in php array

Tags: php

How do I put every file name on the root directory and and all the file names in each sub folder into an array in php?

Comment: What about reading the documentation? What about googling for a suggestion? This forum is not for having someone else do your homework. First try yourself to solve the problem, and if you _really_ are stuck, _then_ is the time to write a question here. A good question, containing teh attempt you did until then, code, problem description and all.

Answer (score 4):

Use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and you'll find a recursive function for sub-directories as well as tons of other examples to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I have always preferred `DirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

Here is an example:

```
function drawArray(DirectoryIterator $directory)
{
    $result=array();
    foreach($directory as $object)
    {
        if($object->isDir()&&!$object->isDot())
        {
            $result[$object->getFilename()]=drawArray(new DirectoryIterator($object->getPathname()));
        }
        else if($object->isFile())
        {
            $result[]=$object->getFilename();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$array=drawArray(new DirectoryIterator('/path'));
print_r($array);
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion using SPL. Recommended!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) [and give condolence to your RAM by the way if you really want to skim **all** your files].

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it.

```
/**
    Recursively returns all the items in the given directory alphabetically as keys in an array, optionally in descending order.
    If a key has an array value it's a directory and its items are in the array in the same manner.
*/
function scandir_tree($directory_name, $sort_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING, $_recursed = false)
    {
    if (!$_recursed || is_dir($directory_name))
        {
        $items = array_diff(scandir($directory_name, (int) $sort_order), ['.', '..']);
        $tree = [];
        foreach ($items as $item)
            {
            $tree[$item] = scandir_tree($directory_name . $item, $sort_order, true);
            }
        return $tree;
        }
    return $directory_name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ar=array();
$g=scandir('..');
foreach($g as $x)
{
    if(is_dir($x))$ar[$x]=scandir($x);
    else $ar[]=$x;
}
print_r($ar);
```